# opensource "Screen Share" application

Tags: screen, share

I am looking for Screen Share Tool.

I am looking for Open-Source Not Commercial as of now.

Preferred in Java.

Please let me know if you have any information related to this.

Thanks
map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using one of the many open source VNC solutions available.

I'd suggest using UltraVNC (http://www.uvnc.com/).

It's open source and there's a Java client (http://www.uvnc.com/features/javaviewer.html). Not sure about the server.

Alternatively, ThinVNC (http://sourceforge.net/projects/thinvnc/) is a VNC server that can be connected to using an HTML5 browser (any modern browser seems to work). Make sure to grab the GPL version as I think this project has been commercialised. The download from Sourceforge should still be GPL.